# Django1.7: ModelForm has no model class specified

Tags: python, django-1.7

I'm getting "ModelForm has no model class specified." error in Django. I've spent hours to get this fixed, but can't see what the problem is.

Thank you very much in advance!

**Traceback:**
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in get_response

111: response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
File "/Users/LandonKoo/code/tango_with_django_project/rango/views.py" in add_category

71: form = CategoryForm()
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/forms/models.py" in **init**

312: raise ValueError('ModelForm has no model class specified.')

Exception Type: ValueError at /rango/add_category/ 
Exception Value: ModelForm has no model class specified.

**forms.py:**

```
from django import forms
from rango.models import Page, Category

class CategoryForm(forms.ModelForm):
    name = forms.CharField(max_length=128, help_text="Please enter the category name.")
    views = forms.IntegerField(widget=forms.HiddenInput(), initial=0)
    likes = forms.IntegerField(widget=forms.HiddenInput(), initial=0)
    slug = forms.CharField(widget=forms.HiddenInput(), required=False)
    print name, views, likes, slug
    # An inline class to provide additional information on the form.
    class Mata:
        # Provide an association between the ModelForm and a model
        model = Category
        fields = ('name',)
```

**views.py:**

```
def add_category(request):

    if request.method=="POST":
        form = CategoryForm(request.POST)

        if form.is_valid():
            form.save(commit=True)

            return index(request)
        else:
            print form.errors
    else:
        form = CategoryForm()

    return render(request, 'rango/add_category.html', {'form': form})
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change

```
class Mata:
```

to

```
class Meta:
```

Also, I have never seen a print statement in a modelform. Take that out just in case too.

Comment: Oh...My... It was a just silly typo :( Thank you so much! It worked.